# Undefined index 'first_name' in Facebook game on laravel 4.2

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, laravel

```php
Route::get('login/fb/callback', function() {
    $code = Input::get('code');
    if (strlen($code) == 0) return Redirect::to('/')->with('message', 'There was an error communicating with Facebook');

    $facebook = new Facebook(Config::get('facebook'));
    $uid = $facebook->getUser();

    if ($uid == 0) return Redirect::to('/')->with('message', 'There was an error');

    $me = $facebook->api('/v2.4/me');
    dd($me);


    $profile = Profile::whereUid($uid)->first();
    if (empty($profile)) {


        $user = new User;
        $user->name = $me['first_name'].' '.$me['last_name'];
        $user->email = $me['email'];
        $user->photo = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$me['username'].'/picture?type=large';

        $user->save();

        $profile = new Profile();
        $profile->uid = $uid;
        $profile->username = $me['username'];
        $profile = $user->profiles()->save($profile);
    }

    $profile->access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
    $profile->save();

    $user = $profile->user;

    Auth::login($user);

    return Redirect::to('/')->with('message', 'Logged in with Facebook');
});
```

I am trying to get the `first_name`, but it's not present. All information I get is the `username` and the `id`.
I think I should chage "/me" to something else,but I cant figure out to what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for "Declarative Fields" in the changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4

You need to add the fields parameter to get additional data:

```
$me = $facebook->api('/v2.4/me?fields=first_name');
```